Apache Flink Reading Parquet Files
Use Case: I have a large data store as parquet files, and I want to go over them using Flink, which I am already using for real time processing.
I am trying to make Flink the parquet files, but have so far failed.
What I tried (and succeeded):

I was able to read parquet data using Table API:

        EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
        TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);

        // Register the Parquet table
        String parquetFilePath = "XX";
        tableEnv.executeSql(
                "CREATE TABLE XX (" +
                        "    XX STRING," +
                        "    XX STRING" +
                        ")  WITH  (" +
                        "    'connector' = 'filesystem'," +
                        "    'path' = '" + parquetFilePath + "'," +
                        "    'format' = 'parquet'" +
                        ")"        );
        TableResult result = tableEnv.executeSql(
                "SELECT XX, COUNT(DISTINCT XX) AS XX " +
                        "FROM XX " +
                        "GROUP BY XX"        );
        result.collect().forEachRemaining(row -> {
            String XX = row.getField(0).toString();
            long YY = (long) row.getField(1);
            System.out.println("XX: " + XX + ", XX: " + YY);
        }); 

problem is I prefer to use Datastream connector rather than table API, to apply business logic using POJO and not SQL Queries.
2. I was also able to read text files using the DataStream connector:
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        FileSource<String> source = FileSource
                .forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineFormat(), new Path("XX"))
                .build();

        DataStream<String> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "file-source");
        stream.print();
        env.execute("Read File and Print");


However these are text files and not parquet.
To read parquet, this is as close as I have gotten, it is able to run, but it doesn't read any parquet files. I get errors like

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LZ4_RAW

and

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.parquet.io.InvalidFileOffsetException

       final Schema schema =
                new Schema.Parser()
                        .parse(
                                "{\"type\": \"record\", "
                                        + "\"name\": \"User\", "
                                        + "\"fields\": [\n"
                                        + "        {\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\" },\n"
                                        + "        {\"name\": \"favoriteNumber\",  \"type\": \"int\" },\n"
                                        + "        {\"name\": \"favoriteColor\", \"type\": \"string\" }\n"
                                        + "    ]\n"
                                        + "    }");

        final FileSource<GenericRecord> source =
                FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(
                                AvroParquetReaders.forGenericRecord(schema),new Path("/Users/pierrekhoury/PycharmProjects/JustTesting/iwhealth/"))
                        .build();

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(10L);

        final DataStream<GenericRecord> stream =
                env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "file-source");

        stream.print();
        env.execute("Read Parquet File and Print");

